# Applandeo Material-Calendar-View, how can I change the language of displayed months?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design, calendarview

I'm using this material calendar view library: https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View

And I can't find how to change the language of the calendar, changing language/location of my emulated phone didn't change anything (I even tried with my personnal phone which is correctly configured.

[Here is the text I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJiVH.png)

Comment: what language do you want to use for those labels?

Comment: @MayurGajra I resolved my problem, it was in Java, but I had to change my strings.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just found the answer on the documentation, hadn't find it in the documentation the last time : [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAiPY.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWCCs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set by using custom labels

```
widget.setTitleFormatter(new MonthArrayTitleFormatter(getResources().getTextArray(R.array.custom_months)));
widget.setWeekDayFormatter(new ArrayWeekDayFormatter(getResources().getTextArray(R.array.custom_weekdays)));
```

And this is on your Strings folder under values

```
<string-array name="custom_weekdays">
    <item>Su</item>
    <item>M</item>
    <item>Tu</item>
    <item>W</item>
    <item>Th</item>
    <item>F</item>
    <item>Sa</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="custom_months">
    <item>JAN</item>
    <item>Feb</item>
    <item>MARCH</item>
    <item>April</item>
    <item>MAY</item>
    <item>June</item>
    <item>JULY</item>
    <item>Aug</item>
    <item>SEPT</item>
    <item>Oct</item>
    <item>Nov</item>
    <item>DEC</item>
</string-array>
```

Have a good day !

Comment: Thanks for your answer but sadly it doesn't work with this library, I've found out the solution, hadn't find it in the documentation the last time...